# ROracle Error in .oci.Driver

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I'm trying to use ROracle. My Oracle database version is Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production, and I have installed Instant Client and SDK for the version 12.1.0.2.0 (12.1.0.1.0 isn't available on Oracle's site).

I can access the Oracle database through Oracle SQL Developer without any issues. The error message I get in RStudio is:

```
Error in .oci.Driver(.oci.drv(), interruptible = interruptible, unicode_as_utf8 = unicode_as_utf8,  :
```

In case it's useful, I have installed Instant Client and SDK here:
C:\oreclient_install_dir\instantclient_12_1

I'm running a Windows machine and I followed the instructions on CRAN:
http://cran.us.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL
Including adding the environment variables.

After some searching (e.g. [here](http://I've%20seen%20this%20posting%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761812/ora-01804-error-while-trying-to-load-oracle-dbdriver)) it looks like I need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ORACLE_HOME and "OCI_LIB", which I did:

```
Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH="C:/oreclient_install_dir/instantclient_12_1")
Sys.setenv("ORACLE_HOME" = "C:/oreclient_install_dir/instantclient_12_1")
Sys.setenv("OCI_LIB" = "C:/oreclient_install_dir/instantclient_12_1")
```

Same error comes up. I'm likely not doing this right, however; I'm not a DBA and don't know all the details.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for Linux. Assuming that you already have Rtools installed in C:\Rtools, you can use the following code to install `ROracle`

```
Sys.setenv(OCI_LIB64="C:\\oreclient_install_dir\\instantclient_12_1")
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste0(Sys.getenv("PATH"),";C:\\oreclient_install_dir\\instantclient_12_1"))
install.packages("ROracle", type="source", INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")
```

For using the ROracle package, you can use the following:

```
Sys.setenv(OCI_LIB64="C:\\oreclient_install_dir\\instantclient_12_1")
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste0(Sys.getenv("PATH"),";C:\\oreclient_install_dir\\instantclient_12_1"))
library(ROracle)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, I get the same error: Error in .oci.Driver(.oci.drv(), interruptible = interruptible, unicode_as_utf8 = unicode_as_utf8,  :

Comment: Neither. It installs and loads just fine. The line is: driver<-Oracle(), or alternatively drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")

Comment: Are there any other installations of Oracle database or client on your machine? You need to check the system environment and registry. Failing which, you might need to reinstall the instant client