# drv <- dbDriver("Oracle") works fine in Command-line R but not working on RStudio Server

Tags: r, oracle, rstudio-server, roracle

as suggested by the title, I'm trying to setup connections to Oracle DBs through R using the library ROracle on a Unix Machine.
using R in command line I have 0 problems, but when trying the same exact instruction in RStudio Server i'm stuc with the following error.

> drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
>   Error in .oci.Driver(.oci.drv(), interruptible = interruptible, unicode_as_utf8 = unicode_as_utf8,  : 
>     Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804

these are the output of libPaths():
in RStudio Server

```
.libPaths()
[1] "/home/rs_violac/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5"
[2] "/usr/lib64/R/library"                                 
[3] "/usr/share/R/library"
```

in R (command line)

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/lib64/R/library" "/usr/share/R/library"
```

I have set the following path:
[image]

and set the LD to the share oracle.conf file as suggested in other stackoverflow answear

```
echo "/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/client/lib" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
```

Any idea or suggestion how to resolve?

EDIT: I've tryed setting those enviornments variable in RStudio console but no resolution

```
Sys.setenv("OCI_INC"="/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/client")
Sys.setenv("OCI_LIB"="/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/client/lib")
Sys.setenv("OCI_LIB64"="/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/client/lib")
Sys.setenv("TNS_ADMIN"="/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/client/network/admin")
Sys.setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"="/usr/lib64/R/lib::/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib:/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/client/lib")
Sys.setenv("ORACLE_HOME"="/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/client")
Sys.setenv("NLS_LANG"="en_US.UTF-8")
Sys.setenv("ORACLE_BASE"="/oracle/app/oracle")
Sys.setenv("LC_ALL"="en_US.UTF-8")
```

Now the error is:

> Error in .oci.Driver(.oci.drv(), interruptible = interruptible,
>   unicode_as_utf8 = unicode_as_utf8,  :    ORA-12715: invalid character
>   set specified

the error change is triggered by the setting of ORACLE_HOME env

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-01804 error while trying to load "Oracle" dbDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761812/ora-01804-error-while-trying-to-load-oracle-dbdriver)

Comment: I do not think so since my ORACL_HOME and LD_LIBRARY path are correctly setted as mentioned in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rstudio user needs to have ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_HOSTNAME set in its environment on the server where the rstudio-server runs. You can use a config file .Renviron, with something like the following for example using BASH shell:

```
ORACLE_HOME=<your Oracle home>
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=<your host name>
export ORACLE_HOME ORACLE_HOSTNAME
```